# Account Number Input Validation C#

Tags: c#, validation, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have been attempting to come up with the proper way to implement a input validation method to check for specific scenarios one them being when the account number is less than 16 or greater. At the moment, I am trying to get it to work if the the 16 digits are present, but it throws the prompt error when it shoudln't.

Here's the custom method I have been working with.
Account Number Pattern: 0000 0000 0000 0000 or 0000-0000-0000-0000.

```
    public static void Validate(string input, int number, string prompt1, string prompt2, string prompt3)
    {
        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || (!(int.TryParse(input, out number))) || number <= 0 || number > 16)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prompt1);
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (input.Split(' ').Length < 16)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Digits");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (!(int.TryParse(input, out number)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prompt2);
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                int.TryParse(input, out number);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prompt3);
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                int.TryParse(input, out number);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what you function is doing. I try to sum it: When `input` is empty, it will ask user to enter a number _(until he gives a number)_. When the number in string is in range 1 to 16 (inclusive) the cycle will end. When the input string contains less than 15 ` ` (space) characters, it writes 'Invalid digits'. If not, it will second time try parse `input` and writes `prompt2` when the parse fails, or `prompt3` when not. In both cases it ask for number. Simple to end the function the input `input`, or entered (console) must be number from 1 to 16. But there is no pattern validation

Comment: And do not forget, that `int.TryParse` can parse a 16 digit number, but the maximal value is `int.MaxValue = 2147483647`. And your number is 16 digits long, therefore first 6 digits must be always zero, when you try to parse it as a single number.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex:

```
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(input, "((\\d{4})-){3}\\d{4}");
```

to validate without Regex you can do it like:

```
string input = "0000-0000-0000-0000";
string[] splited = input.Split('-');
if (splited.Length != 4) splited = input.Split(' ');
bool isValid = splited.All(a => a.Length == 4) && !splited.Any(a => a.Any(b => b < 48 || b > 57));
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7nJlsU)

To Validate without Linq:

```
  private bool IsValid(string input)
  {
      string[] splited = input.Split('-');
      if (splited.Length != 4) splited = input.Split(' ');
      for(int i=0; i< splited.Length; i++)
      {
           if(splited[i].Length!=4) return false;
           for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                 if(splited[i][j]>57 || splited[i][j]<48) return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: I am only looking to do it without regex.

Comment: Nice example _(I'm surptised how simple it can be done)_. Only a few updates. The pattern can contain zero or space. _(`input.Split('-', ' ')` will allow combined pattern with `-` and space, that should probably not be allowed)_, and for better reading I would replace `48` with `'0'` and `57` with `'9'`.

Comment: @Julo I assumed that OP wants either `-` or space as spliter not both. OP please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right, therefore there should be something like this: `string[] splited = input.Split('-'); if (splited.Length == 1) splited = input.Split(' ');`

Comment: no i mean, i thought he means that he will choose one of them and not both.

Comment: You may be right. The question _(format definition)_ can be understood in two ways. _(Or it is only because I'm not a native English speaker?)_

Comment: @Julo me neither. I'm however, even if there is a misunderstanding, OP can correct us, and I think this should have already cleared what is the algorithm I meant

Answer (score 0):

One problem is this

> ```
> else if (input.Split(' ').Length < 16)
> ```

because the result of `string.Split()` is an array of strings. For your case the `Length` of the array will be 4.

But nevertheless the prompt would coming for the next evaluation because you just can't `TryParse` a value of "0000 0000 0000 0000"

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "0000-0000-0000-0000";
string[] splitInput = input.Split('-');
int number = 0;
bool isValid = true;
```

**Method 1:**

```
foreach(var item in splitInput)
{
   if(item.Length != 4 || !int.TryParse(item, out number))
   {
        isValid = false;
        break;
   }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
isValid = splitInput.All(a => a.Length == 4 && int.TryParse(a, out number));
```

Answer (score -1):

may be this can help you something

```
    public static void Validate(string input, int number, string prompt1, string prompt2, string prompt3)
    {
        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || (!(int.TryParse(input, out number))) || number <= 0 || number > 16)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prompt1);
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else 
            {
                var accountNumberInArray = input.Split(' ');
                string accountNumber = string.Empty;
                foreach (var item in accountNumberInArray)
                {
                    accountNumber += item;
                }
                if (accountNumber.Length < 16)
                {
                    //Do something 
                }
                else if (accountNumber.Length > 16)
                {
                    //Do something 
                }
                else if(accountNumber.Length == 16)
                {
                    //Do Something 
                }
            }                
        }
    }
```